# Apply alignments on Reportlab SimpleDocTemplate to append multiple barcodes in number of rows

Tags: python, django, barcode, reportlab

I am using Reportlab `SimpleDocTemplate` to create a pdf file. I have to write (draw) multiple images row-wise so that I can adjust many images within the file.

```
class PrintBarCodes(View):

     def get(self, request, format=None):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;\
        filename="barcodes.pdf"'

        # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
        ean = barcode.get('ean13', '123456789102', writer=ImageWriter())
        filename = ean.save('ean13')
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response, pagesize=A4)
        parts = []
        parts.append(Image(filename))
        doc.build(parts)
        return response
```

In the code, I have printed a single barcode to the file. And, the output is showing in the images as can be seen below.

But, I need to draw a number of barcodes. How to reduce the image size before drawing to the pdf file and adjust in row fashion?

[image]

Comment: Is the answer below what you meant?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks @B8vrede

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question suggest that you need flexibility I think the most sensible approach is using `Flowable`'s. The barcode normally isn't one but we can [make it one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569682/use-qrcodewidget-or-plotarea-with-platypus) pretty easily. By doing so we can let [platypus](/questions/tagged/platypus) decide how much space there is in your layout for each barcode.

So step one the `Barcode` `Flowable` which looks like this:

```
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from reportlab.graphics.barcode.eanbc import Ean13BarcodeWidget
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing
from reportlab.platypus import Flowable

class BarCode(Flowable):
    # Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569682/use-qrcodewidget-or-plotarea-with-platypus
    def __init__(self, value="1234567890", ratio=0.5):
        # init and store rendering value
        Flowable.__init__(self)
        self.value = value
        self.ratio = ratio

    def wrap(self, availWidth, availHeight):
        # Make the barcode fill the width while maintaining the ratio
        self.width = availWidth
        self.height = self.ratio * availWidth
        return self.width, self.height

    def draw(self):
        # Flowable canvas
        bar_code = Ean13BarcodeWidget(value=self.value)
        bounds = bar_code.getBounds()
        bar_width = bounds[2] - bounds[0]
        bar_height = bounds[3] - bounds[1]
        w = float(self.width)
        h = float(self.height)
        d = Drawing(w, h, transform=[w / bar_width, 0, 0, h / bar_height, 0, 0])
        d.add(bar_code)
        renderPDF.draw(d, self.canv, 0, 0)
```

Then to answer your question, the easiest way to now put multiple barcodes on one page would be using a `Table` like so:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("test.pdf", pagesize=A4)

table_data = [[BarCode(value='123'), BarCode(value='456')],
              [BarCode(value='789'), BarCode(value='012')]]

barcode_table = Table(table_data)

parts = []
parts.append(barcode_table)
doc.build(parts)
```

Which outputs:

[image: Example of barcode table]

Comment: can this be extended to code39? It does not have the widget afaik